# Find size of unknown size array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to declare an empty array that takes input from user and then find the length of that array.I have declared empty array but do not know how to take input from user.

Comment: You need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36368337/edit) your post to include what you have done as we cannot see your screen.

Comment: An empty array cannot take input, nor can it have a length greater than 0.  Expand on your question, show us some code, maybe we can help.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size - you can reallocate more memory if needed, but it's easier to use a `List<T>` that can grow dynamically (albeit by reallocating an array behind the scenes).  In that case the `Count` property will give you the number of elements in the collection.

Comment: Side note: Please don't add text like "searched alot" to post - either show what you've found (links + one sentence explanation why it did not work for your case) or don't add anything (no one is going to believe in such statement anyway)

Comment: Yes, use `List` as Stanley suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of exactly what you asked for: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1RSPzs

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var index = 0;
        var myArray = new string[] {};
        var isEmptyText = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Give me some input or press enter to quit: ");
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            isEmptyText = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result);
            if (!isEmptyText) 
            {
                if (myArray.Length <= index) 
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref myArray, index+1);
                }

                myArray[index++] = result;
            }
        } while (!isEmptyText);

        Console.WriteLine(myArray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myArray));
    }
}
```

While that code works, it is re-sizing the array constantly which is a costly procedure. I would advise giving it a reasonable amount of items and them only re-size when required. Like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var index = 0;
        var myArray = new string[25];
        var isEmptyText = false;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Give me some input or press enter to quit: ");
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            isEmptyText = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result);
            if (!isEmptyText) 
            {
                if (myArray.Length <= index) 
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref myArray, myArray.Length + 10);
                }

                myArray[index++] = result;
            }
        } while (!isEmptyText);

        Console.WriteLine(myArray.Length);
        for (var i=0; i < index; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write((i==0 ? "" : ", ") + myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the best thing to do is to use more modern data structures like linked lists or vectors, but sometimes we get these assignments in school and have to figure it out. Check out the generic collections for the easiest data structures to work with in C#: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson20

Comment: Thanks komma8.komma1, it worked for me.

Comment: You may be new to stack overflow, so in the future, try to show what you've tried (the code), and also include a little more detail in your questions. Next, once you have an answer to your question (like my post), you mark the answer so people don't continue to spend time on it thinking it's still open and unanswered.